# What's wrong with my graphics?

Tags: java, user-interface, jpanel, jpeg, paintcomponent

On the first guess, the graphic that's supposed to show up doesn't show. And on the eighth guess, no graphics show up at all. (The user is allowed 10 tries before they lose). Any ideas on why this is happening? Help is appreciated!

HangmanFigure.java

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class HangmanFigure extends JPanel {
   private int guesses;
   private Image background;

      public HangmanFigure() {
         super();
         guesses = 0;
         setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));

         //setting background image to JPEG
         background = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("drac0.jpg");

         //set to true because we want to see the background
         setOpaque(true);
      }

      @Override
      public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
         super.paintComponent(g);

         g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, null);

         //Testing number of guesses
         System.out.println(guesses);

         //right line
         if(guesses >= 1) {
            background = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("drac1.jpg");
            g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, null);
         }

         //top and slant line
         if(guesses >= 2) {
            background = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("drac2.jpg");
            g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, null);
         }

         //string
         if(guesses >= 3) {
            background = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("drac3.jpg");
            g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, null);
         }

         //head
         if(guesses >= 4) {
            background = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("drac4.jpg");
            g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, null);
         }

         //body
         if(guesses >= 5) {
            background = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("drac5.jpg");
            g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, null);
         }

         //left arm
         if(guesses >= 6) {
            background = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("drac6.jpg");
            g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, null);
         }

         //right hand
         if(guesses >= 7) {
            background = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("drac7.jpg");
            g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, null);
         }

         //left leg
         if(guesses >= 8) {
            background = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("drac8.jpg");
            g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, null);
         }

         //right leg
         if(guesses >= 9) {
            background = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("drac9.jpg");
            g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, null);
         }

         //death face and stake
         if(guesses == 10) {
            background = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("drac10.jpg");
            g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, null);
         }
      }

      public void set() {
         guesses++;
         paintComponent(this.getGraphics());
      }
```

Here is my MainWindow.java, where I display everything else in the window:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MainWindow extends JFrame {
   private int remainingGuesses;
   private String wrongGuesses;
   private String word;
   private String visible;

   public MainWindow(String toGuess) {
      remainingGuesses = 10;
      wrongGuesses = "";
      word = toGuess;

      visible = "";

      for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); ++i) {
         visible += "_ ";
      }

      JPanel corePanel = new JPanel();
      corePanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

      final JLabel status = new JLabel("You have "+remainingGuesses+" remaining", SwingConstants.CENTER);
      final JLabel wrong = new JLabel("Wrong guesses so far: "+wrongGuesses);
      final JLabel visibleLabel = new JLabel(visible, SwingConstants.CENTER);
      final JTextField input = new JTextField();

      JPanel southPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 1));
      southPanel.add(status);
      southPanel.add(visibleLabel);
      southPanel.add(input);
      southPanel.add(wrong);

      corePanel.add(southPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

      final HangmanFigure hf = new HangmanFigure();
      corePanel.add(hf, BorderLayout.CENTER);

      this.add(corePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

      input.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String text = input.getText();

            if(text.length()  == 1 && text.matches("[a-z]")) {
               boolean guessFound = false;

               for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); ++i) {
                  if(text.charAt(0) == word.charAt(i)) {
                     guessFound = true;

                     String newVisible = "";

                     for(int j = 0; j < visible.length(); ++j) {
                        if(j == (i*2)) {
                           newVisible += word.charAt(i);
                        }
                        else {
                           newVisible += visible.charAt(j);
                        }
                     }
                     visible = newVisible;
                     visibleLabel.setText(visible);
                  }
               }

               if(!guessFound) {
                  if(--remainingGuesses > 0) {
                     status.setText("You have "+remainingGuesses+" guesses remaining");
                     wrongGuesses += text+" ";
                     wrong.setText("Wrong guesses so far: "+wrongGuesses);
                     hf.set();
                  }
                  else {
                     status.setText("You lost: the word was "+word);
                     input.setEnabled(false);
                  }
               }
               else {
                  String actualVisible = "";
                  for(int i = 0; i < visible.length(); i+=2) {
                     actualVisible += visible.charAt(i);
                  }

                  if(actualVisible.equals(word)) {
                     status.setText("Congratulations, you have won!");
                     input.setEnabled(false);
                  }
               }
            }
            else {
               //displays a dialogue box if user inputs anything other than lowercase letter.
               JFrame frame = new JFrame();
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Please enter a lowercase letter!", "Inane warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            }

            input.setText("");
         }
      });

      this.pack();
      this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      this.setTitle("Hangman");
      this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      this.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      new MainWindow("cat");
   }
}
```

Comment: I think you should use a different Image for the `hangman` figure, right now you are using `background` and overwrites the original image in `paintComponent()`

Comment: Oh ok, so I should put the hangman figure drawings in new Image objects?

Comment: So I changed the Image from background to something else in the first if statement, but now the first graphic doesn't show up until guess 3. :/ Not sure what's going on. :(

Comment: You are painting one picture on top of all the others and the pictures probably aren't transperent, so the white background of the higher images covers the lower image.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Let me try to fix that. :) Hmm....still getting the same problems. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May not be the right / best way to handle this, I don't have any experience with Java Graphics.  But, I looked at the `drawImage` function, and it returns true when the image is ready. So I tried wrapping the calls in a while loop, and now it draws all images.

```
while(!g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, null));
```

[See API reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage(java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.Color,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver))

Sample with your IF statement:

```
  try {

     .....

     if(guesses >= 1) {
        background = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("drac1.jpg");
        // old code - g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, null);
        while(!g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, null)) Thread.sleep(100); // - new code
     }

     if(guesses >= 2) {
        background = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("drac2.jpg");
        // old code - g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, null);
        while(!g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, null)) Thread.sleep(100); // - new code
     }

     .....

    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
       ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you think you could show me how it looks in the code with the first if statement please?? :)

Comment: And does this work if I have different jpg images for each if statement?

Comment: Added sample of an IF statement.  You'll need to change every instance of that line of code (each IF block needs it like that).

Comment: The reason you see the message print out more than once is your windows is receiving more than one paint even.  You print that message out every time your window repaints.  If you resize the window a few times you'll see it print out every time it redraws.

Comment: All the while(!g...) code is doing is to keep trying to draw the image until it gets `true` back from the function call.  There's probably a better solution but like I said I don't have any experience in graphics programming.

Comment: Hmm...so it works up until guess 7, when it gets there, the text box doesn't allow you to type any more and you can't close the window. :(

Comment: You could try adding a delay in the redraw logic, you'd have to wrap your code in a `try-catch` block.  I'll update the answer to show how it would look.

Comment: I think the recommended approach is to do all your drawing to an off-screen surface, and then in your paintComponent method would just draw that single image to the screen.  Known as Double Buffering, you can search for examples if you want to go that route.